# Image with multiple scratcher elements on top of it

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to generate the following UI in flutter. The idea is that there are overlaying pixels on top of an image that can be scratched to remove and reveal the hidden image. These pixels are red/blue/purple in the image below, and covers the image of butterfly in the example.

[image]

I came across this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/scratcher) which allows scratch functionality. However, it seems that the scratch area covers the whole image and can't be colored. before I was trying to do it manually, by drawing these colored squares on top of the image which disappears when clicked. It sounds simple but not easy to implement in flutter.

Further, I generated a matrix of random numbers which I am going to use to color the pixels. When trying to loop over the matrix inside the `Stack` it gives me the error saying: `The element type 'Set<Set<Text>>' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.` Details [here](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages?utm_source=dartdev&utm_medium=redir&utm_id=diagcode&utm_content=list_element_type_not_assignable#list_element_type_not_assignable).

```
Widget paintPixels() {
  return Container(
      child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
        Image(
          width: 350,
          height: 300,
          image: AssetImage('lib/assets/images/orange_butterfly_image.png'),
        ),
        Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
              {
                for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {Text("Hello" + i)}
              }
          ],
        )
      ]));
```

Any suggestions on how to approach the problem?

Comment: I was able to do it without using scratcher. it was easier than expected.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use nested loop to paint the pixeled boxes on top of image. There is no need to use scratcher. Code solution is posted below:

```
  Widget paintPixelsOnReward() {
    int size = 9;
    List<List<num>> matrix = getAlmostRandomMatrix(size);
    return Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
          const Image(
            width: 360,
            height: 315,
            image: AssetImage('lib/assets/images/orange_butterfly_image.png'),
          ),
          Column(children: [
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
              Row(
                children: [
                  for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) ...[
                    LayoutBuilder(
                      builder: (context, constraints) {
                        return Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                          child: Container(
                              width: 40,
                              height: 35,
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  // color: Colors.transparent, // color should be transparent if the pixel has been revealed
                                  color: (matrix[i][j] == 0
                                      ? Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondary
                                      : (matrix[i][j] == 1
                                          ? Theme.of(context)
                                              .colorScheme
                                              .primary
                                          : Theme.of(context)
                                              .colorScheme
                                              .error)),
                                  // Red border with the width is equal to 5
                                  border: Border.all(
                                      width: 1, color: Colors.white))),
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  ]
                ],
              )
          ]),
        ]));
  }
```